# Where to download jquery library from internet?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am new to jquery.I have downloaded `jquery-1.12.2.min.js` from http://jquery.com/download/ ,`jquery-ui.css and jquery-ui.js` from http://jqueryui.com/download/.I want to use some jquery from my web application.Does it safe to use above mentioned js and css from mentioned site?Will it harm my code?

Comment: It is not clear what your question means.  jquery.com is the official jQuery site.  You can download and copy the jQuery files from that site and then host them on your own server or you can link to jQuery directly from a CDN such as https://code.jquery.com/ or https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URLs you've linked are the official sites, so safe to assume that the libraries available to download will not be malicious.